# How can i export portractor report to a remote server

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I'm using the protractor-html-screenshot-reporter in my protractor environment to create the reports and screen shots of failed specs. 
I need to be able to export these results to a remote computer (that i will be able to access from the local computer through an IP address).
is there any way to do it through the reporter package api? or must i find an external solution that will copy the created report to the remote site ?

This is how i use the report on my environment:

```
onPrepare: function(){
 jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new HtmlScreenshotReporter({
        dest: '/Results',
        filename: 'my-report.html',
        showQuickLinks: true,
        reportOnlyFailedSpecs: false,
        captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true,
        restartBrowserBetweenTests: true
    })
 );
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Protractor/Jasmine reporters don't have anything built-in for it.

Move it on a higher level to `grunt`/`gulp` tasks. For example, there is an [`grunt-ssh` task](https://github.com/israelroldan/grunt-ssh) that you can invoke after the testing run to upload the report to the server.